# For flutter while using firebase, how can you organize a collection by timetamp when embedded in a map and reading from a streambuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fluttermap

I am trying to use a streambuilder to read a list of messages (maybe show the 5 most recent), and would like to organize them by timestamp. As you can see the documents are different categories, by the end there will be a few hundred documents, as well as collections and don't wish to make a few hundred collections (left side collection if looking at firestore database as opposed to right collection where I show the message info).

I am writing to the documents this way:

```
   try {
            _firestore.collection('court_feed').doc('category3').set({
            '${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}': {
            'posterUID': '${user?.uid}',
            'posterDisplayName': user?.displayName,
            'content': postContent,
        }
```

When reading from firestore I have a simple stream that looks like this:

```
_firestore.collection('court_feed').doc(category3).snapshots()
```

If using a futurebuilder I could just grab the entire document and organize the maps that way, its not very clean though.

Knowing that I would like to organize these by categories as shown, how can I organize all of these messages by time?

[image]

Comment: Hi does my posted answer help ? If so then acknowledge it, if not then we can solve it further.

Comment: Hi @RohitKharche, this was SO helpful thank you so much! I didn't realize this was an option - may have to go re-do a lot of my other parts now that I know this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your DB snapshot and your code snippet it looks like you are storing messages inside the documents using Map but using `${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}` as a Map name.

As your current structure will not scale because you are storing data as [Nested data in documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#nested_data_in_documents)

Your current db structure will also not give you sorted result instead you can save the documents as an subcollection named messages and use `${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}` as an document id to create your messages something like follows:

```
Firestore Database
└── court_feed - (Collection)
    └── {category3} - Document Id
        └── messages - (sub-collection)
            ├── {DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch} - Document Id
            │   ├── posterUID : string
            │   ├── posterDisplayName : string
            │   └── content : string
            └── {DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch} - Document Id
                ├── posterUID : string
                ├── posterDisplayName : string
                └── content : string
```

Using a structure like this will help you to get the documents order by `${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}` as follows :

```
_firestore
    .collection('court_feed')
    .doc('category3')
    .collection('messages')
    .orderBy(FieldPath.documentId()) //  we can order based on this now
    .snapshots()
```

Now to write the new message in the DB you can follow the following snippet :

```
var category = 'category3';
var documentId = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

_firestore
    .collection('court_feed')
    .doc(category)
    .collection('messages')
    .doc(documentId) //  set a new document id as DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch
    .set({
      'posterUID': '${user?.uid}',
      'posterDisplayName': user?.displayName,
      'content': postContent,
    })
```

Reference : [**Subcollections**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#subcollections)